# Azure Pipelines Integration with Microsoft Teams Possible or Not Possible

Tags: microsoft-teams, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-service-hooks, azure-devops-services

I was going through doc "" [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/integrations/microsoft-teams?view=azure-devops""](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/integrations/microsoft-teams?view=azure-devops%22%22) which says integration of Azure Pipelines with Microsoft Teams is only possible if your project is hosted on Azure Devops Services

So right now my project is hosted on Azure devops Server(TFS) will i able to use "Azure Pipelines with Microsoft Teams"

Comment: Is my reply helpful?

Answer (score 0):

`Azure Pipelines app for Teams` only available on Azure DevOps Services currently. You could submit a user voice at website below for Azure DevOps Server:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=22&entry=suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Azure Pipelines with Microsoft Teams for [Azure devops Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/features-timeline) is a feature under development. Currently it is not possible.